# Fast way to concatenate strings in nodeJS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, concatenation

I understand that doing something like

```
var a = "hello";
a += " world";
```

It is relatively very slow, as the browser does that in `O(n)` . Is there a faster way of doing so without installing new libraries?

Comment: Even if that would be true (that concatenation of strings is very slow), does your code depends on it so heavily that it even matters?

Answer (score 29):

The question is already answered, however when I first saw it I thought of NodeJS Buffer. But it is way slower than the +, so it is likely that nothing can be faster than + in string concetanation.

**Tested with the following code:**

```
function a(){
    var s = "hello";
    var p = "world";
    s = s + p;
    return s;
}

function b(){
    var s = new Buffer("hello");
    var p = new Buffer("world");
    s = Buffer.concat([s,p]);
    return s;
}

var times = 100000;

var t1 = new Date();
for( var i = 0; i < times; i++){
    a();
}

var t2 = new Date();
console.log("Normal took: " + (t2-t1) + " ms.");
for ( var i = 0; i < times; i++){
    b();
}

var t3 = new Date();

console.log("Buffer took: " + (t3-t2) + " ms.");
```

**Output:**

```
Normal took: 4 ms.
Buffer took: 458 ms.
```

Comment: With that buffer, you're initializing a wrapper containing a string, then you're building a array from the 2 wrappers, having the concatenate function loop through the array, (And probably use `+` to concatenate the strings), and return it.
I think that explains why the buffer is slow.

Comment: This test does not capture the intent to concatenate a high number of strings together in linear algorithmic time complexity.

Comment: You're creating two buffers each time inside the loop. It completely defeats the purpose of the test. You should use a single `Buffer` and repeatedly call `write`.

Answer (score 16):

There is not really any other way in JavaScript to concatenate strings.
You could theoretically use `.concat()`, but that's **[way slower](http://jsperf.com/string-concat-plus-vs-native)** than just `+`

Libraries are more often than not slower than native JavaScript, especially on basic operations like string concatenation, or numerical operations.

Simply put: `+` is the fastest.