# Optimize string concat in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, string-concatenation

I am looking to optimize this function. It is part of a large recursive knapsack solving script and gets called several hundred times. **cap** and **item** are passed in as an int, **pLimit** and **tLimit** are arrays.

The string concatenation is causing the function to bog down.
Any ways to optimize this?

```
// Converts subproblem data to string for hashing
function encode(cap, item, pLimit, tLimit) {
    data = cap+","+item+","+pLimit+","+tLimit;

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Maybe try adding all strings to an array, and at the end call `.join(",")` on the array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast way to concatenate strings in nodeJS/JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859543/fast-way-to-concatenate-strings-in-nodejs-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to optimize string concats is to use array based joining.
Hold all the strings as part of array and then join these.

```
var parts = [ "a" , "b", "c" ];

console.log(parts.join(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

In ECMAScript6 you can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
function encode(cap, item, pLimit, tLimit) {
    return `${cap},${item},${pLimit},${tLimit}`;
}
```